# Order of a boolean evaluation

Tags: java, boolean

For any boolean expressions A and B:

will A & B equal B & A

similarly:

will A | B equal B | A

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How about actually **trying** it?

Comment: `|` and `&` are bitwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes those are the same. However, if you change `&` to `&&`, then they won't be same any more.

For example:

```
int a = 10, b = 0;

boolean test  = false && (a / b == 5);  // 1
boolean test2 = (a / b == 5) && false;  // 2

boolean test3 = false & (a / b == 5);   // 3
boolean test4 = (a / b == 5) & false;   // 4
```

Both 3 and 4 will throw an `ArithmeticException`, so they are same. However, while 1 will execute and store `false` in result, 2 will throw an `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: why would that be the case?

Comment: @user2979879 Added an example;

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about Java and you mean `&&` and `||`, than yes, those expressions are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The question need clarification.

If you talking about a && b, when a and b are methods, it will be the following:

First a will be evaluated, then b.

a() && b():
a will be called first, and if it return false, then b() will not be called.

b() && a():
if b return false, then a will not be called.

Practical example:

```
if (obj != null && obj.isXXX())
```

is not equal to

```
if (obj.isXXX() && obj != null)
```

In the first case, all will be fine. In the second NullPointerException will be thrown.

Also, a && b not equal to b && a in the case, when a or b can change the state.